# return when user clicks a children of a anchor

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, next.js

I want to return the following function if the user clicks a children of the anchor:

```html
<a href="/product/product-id">
I am a product
  <div>
    Add to favorites
   </div>
</a>
```

```js
const handleClick = (event) =>{
  console.log(event);
  
  // true -> if i click any of its children aka. the add to favorites
  if(true){
    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  
  // Route is about to change
  NProgress.start();
}

document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

How can i do such thing?

### Edit 1:

This is my react.js/next13/next14 code:

```
'use client';

export default function NextNProgress() {
    useEffect(() => {
        NProgress.configure();

        function isAnchorOfCurrentUrl(currentUrl: string, newUrl: string) {
            const currentUrlObj = new URL(currentUrl);
            const newUrlObj = new URL(newUrl);
            // Compare hostname, pathname, and search parameters
            if (
                currentUrlObj.hostname === newUrlObj.hostname &&
                currentUrlObj.pathname === newUrlObj.pathname &&
                currentUrlObj.search === newUrlObj.search
            ) {
                // Check if the new URL is just an anchor of the current URL page
                const currentHash = currentUrlObj.hash;
                const newHash = newUrlObj.hash;
                return (
                    currentHash !== newHash &&
                    currentUrlObj.href.replace(currentHash, '') === newUrlObj.href.replace(newHash, '')
                );
            }
            return false;
        }

        const htmlElements = document.querySelectorAll('html');

        function findClosestAnchor(element: HTMLElement | null): HTMLAnchorElement | null {
            while (element && element.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'a') {
                element = element.parentElement;
            }
            return element as HTMLAnchorElement;
        }

        function handleClick(event: MouseEvent) {
            try {
                const target = event.target as HTMLElement;
                const anchor = findClosestAnchor(target);
                const newUrl = anchor?.href;
                if (newUrl) {
                    const currentUrl = window.location.href;
                    // const newUrl = (anchor as HTMLAnchorElement).href;
                    const isExternalLink = (anchor as HTMLAnchorElement).target === '_blank';
                    const isBlob = newUrl.startsWith('blob:');
                    const isAnchor = isAnchorOfCurrentUrl(currentUrl, newUrl);
                    if (newUrl === currentUrl || isAnchor || isExternalLink || isBlob || event.ctrlKey) {
                        NProgress.start();
                        NProgress.done();
                        [].forEach.call(htmlElements, function (el: Element) {
                            el.classList.remove('nprogress-busy');
                        });
                    } else {
                        NProgress.start();
                        (function (history) {
                            const pushState = history.pushState;
                            history.pushState = function () {
                                NProgress.done();
                                [].forEach.call(htmlElements, function (el: Element) {
                                    el.classList.remove('nprogress-busy');
                                });
                             
                                return pushState.apply(history, arguments as any);
                            };
                        })(window.history);
                    }
                }
            } catch (err) {
                NProgress.start();
                NProgress.done();
            }
        }

        // Add the global click event listener
        document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
        };
    }, []);

    return styles;
}
```

For those who were asking why i tagged this as react/next... this is the code i hacked to work with nprogress library... I think next will soon add router events back but for the mean time this is what i have done so far...

Comment: Why are you using a `<div>` instead of a `<span>`? That said, the event listener goes on "the thing for which the handler needs to kick in", so that's definitely not `document` in this case.

Comment: Our codebase is like this... Sometimes it's a `<button>` sometimes a `span` and sometimes a regular `div`.

Comment: <button> is the best semantical choice.

Comment: Then now is the time to fix things, because that's just a span of text, not a content division. @RomanKurbatov this is a link to a URL, and so should absolutely be an anchor, not a button.

Comment: I mean. I also simplified a lot the code. It's a div that has a lottie inside (an animated heart icon). With a click event and classNames etc..

Comment: @CarlosDubón that's still something a span can trivially do =) (but in terms of why things don't work: put the event listener on the right DOM node)

Comment: Anyway, as for your questions - what's the problem?
<div onClick={handleClick} /> for any children. No need to add the listener, it's not the react way.

Comment: Are you trying to add a click handler to the `<div>` and then stop the propagation of the event?  Something else?  Why is that part of the `<a>` in the first place?  Why is this tagged with React at all?  This is looking more and more like an XY Problem...

Comment: My issue is that Next.js 13 removed router events. Specifically the router.on('routeChangeStart'). So I hacked the NProgress library to kinda work. I listen to all anchor tags in my site and when the user clicks them i do NProgress.start(). Then when url changes I do NProgress.done(). The issue is that it's also saying that the route is starting to change when it's not. This happens because of the above scenario that I'm wondering how to fix...

Comment: @CarlosDubón: If the `<div>` shouldn't trigger the `<a>` then remove it from the `<a>`?

Comment: @David That would suppose a major refactor to the site. But could be a possible solution yes..

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of achieving your objective would be to add an event listener directly to the `div` inside the first `a` element:

```js
document.querySelector("a>div").addEventListener("click",ev=>{
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log('take action on "Add to favorites"');
});
```

```html
<a href="/product/product-id">
I am a product
  <div>
Add to favorites
   </div>
</a>
```

As there was nothing React specific in the question I provided the above answer for a page with Vanilla JavaScript. This is probably not "the React way" of doing things.

If you want to work with the "global event handler" you can try the following:

```js
const handleClick = ev =>{
  console.log(ev.type);
  
  // In case the clicked element is a direct child of an A element:
  if(ev.target.closest("div").parentNode.tagName=="A"){
    console.log("Cart action ...");
    ev.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  
  // Route is about to change
  // NProgress.start();
}

document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```html
<a href="/product/product-id">
I am a product
  <div>
Add to<br><br><span><b>favorites</b><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"></span>
   </div>
</a>
```

Comment: this didn't worked. the global document event listener also runs...

Comment: your update also didn't worked. Because the Add to favorites button is a div that contains a lottie, Depending on where the user clicks the heart icon. ev.target.parentNode.tagName returns "g" or "DIV".

Comment: I only had the question post to work on . If you want more reliable answers you will need to post more details about your actual situation/problem.

Comment: Please have another look at my modified answer (second snippet).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `event.stopPropagation` in your `<div>` element.

Something like this:

**HTML**

```
<a href="/product/product-id">
  I am a product
  <div id="1" class="favorite-button">Add to favorites</div>
</a>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
  const likeButtons = document.querySelector(".favorite-button");


  likeButtons.forEach((likeButton) => likeButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    // your rules here
  } ))
</script>
```

I hope helped you